# Shortish bitwise method of rouding towards zero to nearest 0x50?

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, rounding, 6800

I'm trying to patch an old 8-bit assembler routine (it happens to be M6800 but this isn't really machine specific) to take a 16-bit value and round down to the nearest 0x50 (dec 80) multiple. The current code truncates to nearest **32** by just doing one `AND 0xE0` to the low byte which of course neatly zeroes out the low 5 bits and gets the correct result without touching the high byte.

This is doing some screen math and so the input values will only be in the range of `0xE000` to `0xE7CF`. Since 80 is obviously not a power of two, I can't do it trivially, but given that this is a patch I'm trying to keep the number of instructions to a minimum ideally without adding generic division or lookup tables, etc.

I'm stumped and suspect there is no especially clever way to accomplish this. 80 is not a power of two but it is a multiple of 16... doesn't that help me at all?? Any insights, pointers, or etc are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 0x50 isn't a power of 2, so it has odd prime factors.  That makes it fundamentally harder on a binary computer.  Quotient and remainder both depend on all the higher bits of the whole integer.  Like probably needing a multiplicative inverse or something.  Are you optimizing for code-size or speed?  A loop could maybe search iteratively for an exact multiple or not, but IDK if that would be shorter or not, let alone useful.

Comment: The "obvious" way is `x - (x%0x50)`, but remainder with a multiplicative inverse would involve a multiply and subtract anyway, so `x / 0x50 * 0x50` is the general way.  I assume it's pretty expensive on 6800 to do 16x16 => 32-bit multiplication to get the high half for the x / 0x50 part, so that might or might not be worse a shift-and-sub loop for standard bitwise division.  Either way, if you get a quotient, it will fit in 10 bits, so it's not quite as cheap as just 8x8 => 16-bit, although that multiply can be done manually via shift/add.

Comment: Putting together the anwers with the limited input range: You add the two middle hex digits giving you a (decimal) result between 0 (0+0) to 21 (0x6 + 0xf). From this result you need the remainder of division by 5, multiplied by 16 (resulting in either 0/16/32/48/64). Either by some comparisons to have the 5 cases: 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, which can be subtracted from 0..21 and left-shifted by 4; the comparisons can be done like a tree; or by a very small LUT). The original input number has to be ANDed with 0xFFF0 and this number 0..64 subtracted. That gives your result for rounding down to 0x50.

Comment: The middle hex digits you can get by ANDing the higher byte with 0xf and adding the lower byte right-shifted by 4. I would guess, you need about 20 bytes of ROM memory for this patch.

Comment: Should `0xE000` output `0` (beginning of region) or `64` (remainder of division of full number)? With 0x20 (instead of 0x50) both answers are `0`.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, since `80 = 16 * 5`, rounding down to a multiple of `80` means rounding down to a multiple of both `16` and `5`. The first one is easy with a right shift, so now we're left with the `mod 5` part:

```py
def mod5(x):
    return x % 5

def round80(x):
    x >>= 4
    x -= mod5(x)
    x <<= 4
    return x
```

`mod5` isn't that easy to do, but there is a [clever construction for Mersenne moduli](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/%7Ejones/bcd/mod.shtml#exmod5) that first calculates `mod15`, and then brings the value down to be modulo 5. It's not that intuitive at first, but it only involves additions and shifts, which should be easy enough to implement. Here's the python version:

```py
def mod15(x):
    x = (x >> 8) + (x & 0xFF)
    x = (x >> 4) + (x & 0xF)
    if x >= 15: x -= 15
    if x >= 15: x -= 15 # (see note)
    return x

def mod5(x):
    x = mod15(x)
    if x >= 5: x -= 5
    if x >= 5: x -= 5
    return x

def round80(x):
    x >>= 4
    x -= mod5(x)
    x <<= 4
    return x
```

To be safe, I verified this code for all possible values:

```py
for i in range(0x10000):
    trivial = i - (i % 80)
    assert trivial == round80(i)
```

One additional note: the second `if` inside of `mod15` can actually be omitted *for your input range*, commenting it out made no difference. If you need the whole `[0,0xffff]` range, you cannot remove it.

I'm no expert in M6800 assembly so I'm not going to attempt writing the final code, but it should be relatively simple, especially given that the only 16 bit operations are the two shifts and the first addition in `mod15`.

No division, no multiplication and no lookup tables - I hope this is short enough for your needs!

Comment: `x >> 8` and `x & 0xFF` are free on an 8-bit CPU that has to keep 16-bit numbers in two 8-bit halves.  So yeah, even better trick! (Although carry-out can still make a 9-bit result).   (6800 has one 16-bit "IX" index register other than the stack pointer and PC (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_6800#MC6800_microprocessor_design); IDK if IX is usable for any 16-bit addition or shifts.  It has only two 8-bit data registers, A and B, which is pretty cramped so this will likely need some scratch space in memory, but yeah this should be vastly better than the general case modulo / rounding.

Comment: http://www.8bit-era.cz/6800.html lists the instruction set.  Seems shifts are only 8-bit and 1 count at a time, so right-shifting a 16-bit integer will take some work to get bits across the boundary.  Like 4x (LSR B / ROR A).  There is support for 16-bit compares if you get the data into IX, like `CPX #5`.  But no support for add/sub on IX, although DEX/INX (IX-- or ++) are 1-byte instructions.  So yeah, there's a bunch of things to consider for an efficient 6800 implementation of this, but should be possible.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/TbGeKG5be shows GCC for AVR, which is also 8-bit but has 32 registers vs. 6800's two regs.  And it has a `swap` instruction to rotate by 4, swapping nibbles in a byte.  So it's actually a lot more efficient at `x >> 4` than 6800 would be.  I translated this to C, using `uint8_t` whenever possible, and tried to get compilers to do a more efficient job with the `if(m >= 5) m -= 5;`, to subtract and use FLAGS from it instead of a separate compare.  To save code size, you could just let a `do( m -= 5; }while( (int8_t)m >= 0 );` loop run, followed by `m+=5`, never doing -=15.

Answer (score 8):

We take Darios trick and apply it to the limited input range.

As 80 can be divided by 16, we can, in order to round down to the next multiple of 80, discard the rightmost hex digit (set it to zero) and round down the number left of this digit to the next multiple of 5.

That can be done by determining the remainder of such a division and subtracting it. The leftmost digit is a constant 0xE. 0xE00 mod 5 = 4. The second digit is in the hexadecimal system multiplied by 16. 16 mod 5 = 1. So the remainder of the division by 5 is 4 + second digit + third digit.

As we have to shift the input bytes to get to the middle digits and shift back to subtract from the input (or as an alternate way, subtract to and from a shifted number and shift back the difference), we can also do our calculations with numbers shifted to the left, as long as they fit into a byte to save shift operations.

The maximum sum of the two middle digits and 4 is 4 + 0x6 + 0xf = 25. So we can calculate with numbers up to 8x as high to stay below 255.

There are different ways to get the remainder of a division by 5 from a number between 4 and 25. Either by a loop or by a series of tests of the range and branching. (Branches and memory accesses are cheap on those early processors compared to today's.) We have to find a compromise between execution time and code size.

Instead of tests in order to set the flags for branching, we can do actual calculations and branch dependent on the result, which also saves instructions.

The used flags are Carry, Zero and Sign.

Carry/Borrow gives us the information that the previous addition or subtraction went above 255 or below 0 and wrapped around.

Zero/Equal tells us that the result was 0.

Sign gives us the most significant bit, or that the previous sum is actually 16 or higher, if we do all the calculations multiplied by 8. 16*8=128, which is the value of the MSB of an 8 bit unsigned int.

Assuming the index register points to the high byte of the input number followed by the low byte in memory (big endian convention as was often used by Motorola, but the indices can be simply changed in the following code, when accessing memory).

```
    LDAA #00H,X ; load high byte into A
    ANDA #0FH   ; take lower digit
    LDAB #01H,X ; load low byte into B
    ANDB #F0H   ; select higher digit of B
    ASLA        ; do everything with numbers * 8
    ASLA
    ASLA
    LSRB        ; shift right by 1
    ABA         ; add B to A
    ADDA #20H   ; add 8*4 for contribution of 0xE000
AGAIN:
    SUBA #28H   ; subtract 8*5
    BCC AGAIN   ; no borrow, do it again
    ADDA #28H   ; we subtracted once too much, undo
    ASLA        ; multiply by 2 again
    TAB         ; transfer A to B
    LDAA #01H,X ; load low byte into A
    ANDA #F0H   ; set lower digit to 0
    SBA         ; subtract B from A, keep carry
    STAA #01H,X ; store low byte back
    BCC FINISHED; no borrow occured
    DEC #00H,X  ; borrow -> decrement high byte
FINISHED:
```

This solution takes 34 bytes and executes up to 30 instructions (and minimally executes 20).

Variant 1:

```
    LDAA #00H,X ; load high byte into A
    ANDA #0FH   ; take lower digit
    LDAB #01H,X ; load low byte into B
    ANDB #F0H   ; select higher digit of B
    ASLA        ; do everything with numbers * 8
    ASLA
    ASLA
    LSRB        ; shift right by 1
    ABA         ; add B to A
    BPL PLUS0_15; 0..15
    SUBA #(21*8); 16..21 -21
    BCC GOOD    ; 21     change = -21
    ADDA #(5*8) ; 16..20 -21+5
    BRA GOOD    ;        change = -16
PLUS0_15:       ; 0..15
    BNE PLUS1_15; 1..15
    ADDA #(4*8) ; 0      +4
    BRA GOOD    ;        change = +4
PLUS1_15:       ; 1..15
    SUBA #(11*8);        -11
    BCC GOOD    ; 11..15 change = -11
    ADDA #(5*8) ;        -11+5
    BCS GOOD    ; 6..10  change = -6
    ADDA #(5*8) ; 1..5   -11+5+5
                ;        change = -1
GOOD:
    ASLA        ; multiply by 2 again
    TAB         ; transfer A to B
    LDAA #01H,X ; load low byte into A
    ANDA #F0H   ; set lower digit to 0
    SBA         ; subtract B from A, keep carry
    STAA #01H,X ; store low byte back
    BCC FINISHED; no borrow occured
    DEC #00H,X  ; borrow -> decrement high byte
FINISHED:
```

This solution takes 52 bytes and executes up to 24 instructions (and minimally executes 19). Faster, but larger.

Variant 2:

```
    LDAA #00H,X ; load high byte into A
    ANDA #0FH   ; take lower digit
    LDAB #01H,X ; load low byte into B
    ANDB #F0H   ; select higher digit of B
    ASLA        ; do everything with numbers * 8
    ASLA
    ASLA
    LSRB        ; shift right by 1
    ABA         ; add B to A
    BPL PLUS0_15; 0..15
    SUBA #(21*8); 16..21 -21
    BRA SAMECODE
    ;BCC GOOD   ; 21     change = -21
    ;ADDA #(5*8); 16..20 -21+5
    ;BRA GOOD   ;        change = -16
PLUS0_15:       ; 0..15
    CMPA #(6*8);
    BCC PLUS6_15; 6..15
    SUBA #(6*8) ;        -1
    BRA SAMECODE
    ;BCC GOOD   ; 1..5   change = -1
    ;ADDA #(5*8); 0      -1+5
    ;BRA GOOD   ;        change = +4
PLUS6_15:       ; 6..15
    SUBA #(11*8);        -11
SAMECODE:
    BCC GOOD    ; 11..15 change = -11
    ADDA #(5*8) ;        -11+5
GOOD:
    ASLA        ; multiply by 2 again
    TAB         ; transfer A to B
    LDAA #01H,X ; load low byte into A
    ANDA #F0H   ; set lower digit to 0
    SBA         ; subtract B from A, keep carry
    STAA #01H,X ; store low byte back
    BCC FINISHED; no borrow occured
    DEC #00H,X  ; borrow -> decrement high byte
FINISHED:
```

This solution takes 46 bytes and executes up to 24 instructions (and minimally executes 20). A good bit smaller with code reuse, a bit worse optimal case, same worst case. One should better compare the average case.

Variant 3:

```
    LDAA #00H,X ; load high byte into A
    ANDA #0FH   ; take lower digit
    LDAB #01H,X ; load low byte into B
    ANDB #F0H   ; select higher digit of B
    ASLA        ; do everything with numbers * 8
    ASLA
    ASLA
    LSRB        ; shift right by 1
    ABA         ; add B to A
    BPL PLUS0_15; 0..15
    SUBA #(21*8); 16..21 -21
    BCC GOODA   ; 21     change = -21
    BRA SAMECODE
    ;ADDA #(5*8); 16..20 -21+5
    ;BRA GOODA  ;        change = -16
PLUS0_15:       ; 0..15
    SUBA #(6*8) ;
    BCS PLUS0_5 ; 0..5
    TAB         ; Transfer A to B (keep safe for 6..10)
    SUBA #(5*8) ;        -6-5
    BCC GOODA   ; 11..15 change = -11
    BRA GOODB   ; 6..10 change = -6
PLUS0_5:        ; 0..5
    ADDA #(5*8) ;        -6+5
    BCS GOODA   ; 1..5   change = -1
SAMECODE:
    ADDA #(5*8) ; 0      -6+5+5
                ;        change = +4
GOODA:
    TAB         ; transfer A to B
GOODB:
    ASLB        ; multiply by 2 again
    LDAA #01H,X ; load low byte into A
    ANDA #F0H   ; set lower digit to 0
    SBA         ; subtract B from A, keep carry
    STAA #01H,X ; store low byte back
    BCC FINISHED; no borrow occured
    DEC #00H,X  ; borrow -> decrement high byte
FINISHED:
```

This solution takes 51 bytes and executes up to 23 instructions (and minimally executes 19). Larger again, but even better worst case.

A more conventional solution (also working with other divisors than 0x50):

```
    LDAA #00H,X ; load high byte
    SUBA #DCH   ; subtract 0xDC; 0xDC00 is divisible by 80; prevent overflow of counter, shorten execution time; we know input is at least 0xE000
    CLR  #00H,X ; clear counter
    LDAB #01H,X ; load low byte
REP1:
    INC #00H,X  ; count
    SUBB #50H   ; try subtracting 0x50
    SBCA #00H   ; subract with borrow
    BCC REP1    ; not finished
    LDAA #DBH   ; initialize high byte with 0xDB
    LDAB #B0H   ; initialize low byte with 0xB0 (counter is 1 too high)
REP2:
    ADDB #50H   ; add 0x50 to low byte
    ADCA #00H   ; add carry to high byte
    DEC #00H,X  ; decrease counter
    BNE REP2    ; until zero
    STAB #01H,X ; store back low byte
    STAA #00H,X ; store back high byte
```

This solution needs 32 bytes and executes up to 312 instructions (minimum 112). At least smaller in size.

As comparison the approach with rounding down to multiples of 0x20 instead of of 0x50:

```
    LDAA #01H,X ; load low byte
    ANDA #E0H   ; zero the 5 low bits
    STAA #01H,X ; store back
```

would need 6 bytes and execute 3 instructions.

Comment: Oh right, the limited input range means the high 4 bits are always the same!  And the initial right shift by 4 means that we only have 8 totals bits that aren't known or being shifted out as part of the factor of 16.  The `x = (x >> 8) + (x & 0xFF)` step can produce a carry to the 9th bit, though; is that being dealt with? Or is there a reason it can't happen in the limited-range case?

Comment: Also, like I suggested in my answer, can we right-shift less before the add, so we have less to undo?  Like two `lsrb` and two `asl a` to start, then one `anda #FFH << 2` after the add, and use `suba #05 << 2`.  That's two fewer shifts, and the same numbers and size of other instructions.  Hmm, but would still need the `anda #0FH` before left-shifting that part, so it's not pure win, trading two shifts for one extra `anda #imm8`.  If we can get away with only one right shift before adding, then we save another 1 net.  (1 right, 1 left of the result.  3 left for the other input.)

Comment: @PeterCordes you are right, the contribution of the 0xE000 was missing. 0xE00 % 15 == 14. So I added 4. Now (after subtracting 0xE000 and right-shifting by 4) we actually have a 2 digit-number (hexadecimally), with which the `x = (x >> 8) + (x & 0xFF)` is a no-op.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, we can save two shifts for one and. Does not save space, but execution of one instruction. Due to the fix for the 0xe000 we cannot save three shifts :-(

Comment: @PeterCordes We could rewrite the comparison of the loop in the first solution: Instead of subtracting and then testing if we overshot, we can CMPA, if it is high enough. This saves the undo ADDA and makes it possible to do the 0xE000 correction after the loop (because we can consider the following addition beforehand in the CMPA constant). With it we could save three shifts instead of two. Overall it would save one byte, but the loop has one instruction more and the saved shift does not time-compensate for the instruction in the loop, which one average is executed a bit more than three times.

Comment: Cool, thanks for looking into the details of those ideas.  To optimize dynamic instruction count over static code-size, perhaps Dario's idea of separate `-=15` corrections could be useful, like one cmpa/branch forward over a `suba`.  Or `suba`/`bcc` with `-=15<<2` until overshooting, and then `adda #5<<2`/`bcc` until we come back up above zero.  Best case neither branch is taken (1 sub 1 add), worst case the first is taken once or twice, the 2nd is taken twice for 2 subs and 3 adds. (+ bcc for each).  If the input to that step is uniformly distributed over some range, that maybe isn't great.

Comment: The CMPA variant with 3 shifts saved has the problem, that two branch instructions are needed, as we cannot find out, whether we are in the beginning of the loop (and A is high because of that) or A is high, because the subtraction let it fall below zero. The two branches in the loop makes it (except the best case) worse in size and execution time. We would need CMPA or a subtraction which uses a boolean operation on the flags. (not available on those microcontrollers ..., but on newer processors)

Comment: The input range is limited from above, that means the second digit is way below 0xf. So we can save 3 shifts after all.

Comment: We have the cases: Sum of digits: 0..21, with correction and mod 5 (0: +4, 1..5: -1, 6..10: -6, 11..15: -11, 16..20: -16, 21:-16). We can directly test for case 0 (zero flag) and for the last two cases (sign flag, when shifted 3 to the left).

Comment: @PeterCordes: See new variant implementing comparisons and piecewise adds/subs

Comment: Cool!  Neat that branching on the sign bit allows us to keep the worst case not too bad with that.

Comment: @PeterCordes Changing CMPA to SUBA and storing in B with combining with the anyway afterwards used TAB got 1 less instruction in the worst case.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't clever math or bit-twiddling, but you might consider a simple loop if you're optimizing for code space.  With your input range there are only 26 possible output values so the worst-case runtime isn't terrible.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>

/* Truncate to nearest multiple of 80, with input range 0xE000 to 0xE7D0. */
uint16_t truncate_to_80(uint16_t n) {
    uint16_t ret = 0xDFC0; /* Lowest possible output. */
    while (ret+80 <= n) {
        ret = ret+80;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(void) {
    for (int i = 0xE000; i <= 0xE7D0; i++) {
        uint16_t truncated = truncate_to_80(i);
        assert(truncated == (i - (i % 80)));
        printf("%d -> %d\n", i, truncated);
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this is vastly smaller code-size compiled for an 8-bit machine.  https://godbolt.org/z/TbGeKG5be shows GCC for AVR, which is also 8-bit but has 32 registers vs. 6800's two regs.  And it has a `swap` instruction to rotate by 4, swapping nibbles in a byte.  So it's actually a lot more efficient at `x >> 4` than 6800 would be.  I translated Dario's version to C, using `uint8_t` whenever possible.  This is still many fewer instructions of static code size.

Answer (score 3):

0x50 isn't a power of 2, so it has odd prime factors. That makes it fundamentally harder on a binary computer. Quotient and remainder both depend on all the higher bits of the whole integer.

Dario's mod5 idea taking advantage of the 2^n + 1 special case is quite useful, avoiding the full general case of a multiplicative inverse or a shift/add iterative division.

It's still somewhat painful, especially since 6800 (unlike AVR) can only shift by 1.  AVR's `swap` instruction (exchanging nibbles = rotate by 4) is useful here, with compilers making good use of it to shift by 4, for a C version of Dario's code  (https://godbolt.org/z/c7qhKx6aY).

AVR is another 8-bit microcontroller, so it's somewhat interesting to see how compilers do things there.  It has 32 registers, vs. [6800's two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_6800#MC6800_microprocessor_design) (plus a 16-bit IX, but operations on that are quite limited: http://www.8bit-era.cz/6800.html lists the instruction set).  It only has shifts by 1, nothing like AVR's `swap` that I can see, so shifting by 4 is more expensive.  (Shifting by 8 is still free, 16-bit numbers are still stored in 8-bit halves.)

I introduced new `uint8_t` variables where values were narrow enough for that, helping compilers avoid wasting instructions.  (And identifying those spots for a hand-written asm version.)  I also rewrote things to potentially do less shifting, especially less full 16-bit shifting, but I think there's more room for such optimizations by hand, e.g. maybe working with shifted values to return a `mod5 << 4` directly, instead of making the caller do that.

e.g. `(x >> 4) + (x & 0xF)` could potentially be `(x & 0xf0) + ((uint8_t)x<<4)`, but that wouldn't make it fit within a byte; there's still be a bit that might extend into the next byte.  Perhaps only right shift one or two bit positions, so there's less distance to shift back after using 8-bit subtraction to do the `m -= 15` and `m -= 5` steps.

Otherwise at least the first of those steps would have to deal with the top of the value extending into another byte.  Borrow only propagates from low to high, but you do need to compare correctly so you can't just truncate and discard it; that would be mod 16 not mod 15.

```c
#include <stdint.h>

inline
uint8_t mod15(unsigned short x){
    x = (x >> 8) + (x & 0xFF);     // carry-out can produce a 9-bit result
    uint8_t m = (x >> 4) + (x & 0xF);
#if 0
    do {
         m -= 15; 
    } while((int8_t)m >= 0);
    m += 15;
#else
    if(m >= 15) m -= 15;
    //if(m >= 15) m -= 15; // not needed for partial range
#endif
  // or slower, just let a mod5 loop run potentially more iterations
    return m;
}

inline
uint8_t mod5(unsigned short x){
    uint8_t m = mod15(x);
    //while(!__builtin_sub_overflow(m, 5, &m) ){}
    //m += 5;

    //uint8_t m1 = m - 5;
    //if (m < 5) return m1;
#if 1
    do {  // GCC makes a small loop, clang calls a modulo function :/
         m -= 5;
    } while((int8_t)m >= 0);
    m += 5;
#else
    if(m >= 5) m -= 5;
    if(m >= 5) m -= 5;
#endif
    return m;
}

unsigned short round80(unsigned short x){
    //x >>= 4;
    uint8_t m5 = mod5(x>>4);
    x &= -16;
    x -= m5 << 4;
    //x <<= 4;
    return x;
}
```

I haven't yet actually tried to write a 6800 version of it; it would very likely need some scratch space, either on the stack with push / pull, or some cheaper to access space somewhere.  With only 2 8-bit registers A and B, that's the whole value.

16-bit right shift by 1 can be done with `LSR B` / `ROR A`.  That does need to happen at some point I think, but perhaps can be avoided as much as possible if it's going to be un-done later.

Answer (score 3):

As already written in other answers, I would use the fact that 80=5*16:

This allows you to round down to the nearest multiple of 80 using the following algorithm (shown as C-like code):

```
/* Step 1: Clear the lower 4 bits */
X = X & ~0xF;
/* Step 2: Round down the upper N-4 bits to a multiple of 5 */
X -= ((X >> 4) % 5) << 4;
```

The first step is a simple AND operation.

The operation `(X >> 4) % 5` can be performed using the following pseudo code for a 16-bit number:

```
# A, H and L are 8-bit registers or memory locations
A = 0
H:L = X
REPEAT 12 TIMES
    A:H:L <<= 1
    A -= 5
    IF A < 0
        A += 5
    END_OF_IF
END_OF_LOOP
# Now A contains (X >> 4) % 5
```

I didn't work with 6800 code since the early 1990s, so the following code may be wrong:

```
# RAM locations:
#  [X_low] = Initially holding low 8 bits of the number;
#            finally holding low 8 bits of the result
#  [X_high] = ... high 8 bits ...
#  [TmpH] = Temporary memory;
#           corresponds to "H" in pseudo-code
#  [TmpL] = Temporary memory; ... "L" ...

# Step one: Clear the lower 4 bits
LDAA [X_low]
ANDA #0xF0
STAA [X_low]

# Prepare for step two
# Note: AccA still contains X_low
STAA [TmpL]
LDAA [X_high]
STAA [TmpH]
CLR A
LDAB #12

# The loop
loop:
ASL [TmpL]
ROL [TmpH]
ROL A
SUBA #5
BCC notSmallerThanZero
ADDA #5
notSmallerThanZero:
DEC B
BNE loop

# Now AccA contains (X >> 4) % 5
# Calculate ((X >> 4) % 5) << 4
ASL A
ASL A
ASL A
ASL A

# ... and subtract that value from X
TAB
LDAA [X_low]
SBA
BCC noCarry
DEC [X_high]
noCarry:
STAA [X_low]
```