# Division Using Shift In Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, arm, keil, lpc

I am new to assembly programming and I have a question.

I learned that LSL is faster than MUL instruction and we can use the LSL for multiplication by 2 and LSR for division by 2.
Moreover, in the multiplication case, we can do some tricks such as the multiplication by 3 using shift and add

```
mov r0,#2  
mov r1,r0    ; saving a copy of r0 for adding later
lsl r0,#1    ; multiplying r0 with 2 by shifting left 1 bit
add r0,r1    ; adding the originial r0 to get the multiplication-by-3 result
```

Is there a similar method for division? for example, if I have the number 9 and I want to divide it by 3, what operations could be done for such a case.

Comment: You cannot divide by three using a right shift.  However, you can use a multiplication with a magic constant to do it.  See e.g. [this article](https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~jones/bcd/divide.html) for an explanation.

Comment: Compile `unsigned f(unsigned x){return x/3;};` *with optimization* and look at its assembly output. You'll see how it can be optimized. Also try with `int` instead of `unsigned` or different constant divisors other than `3`.

Comment: In base 2 an unsigned divide by a power of 2 can be done with a shift, in base 10 you can do the same with a power of 10.  1200/10 = 120.  only works if you are in the same base or a power of the base (can use a binary, base 2,  shifter to divide base 4 or 8 or 16...)

Comment: Also Hacker's Delight has a wonderful chapter about this subject. There are apparently many links online for a free read but not sure about their legality..

Comment: Related: [Shortish bitwise method of rouding towards zero to nearest 0x50?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72537823) points out a trick for a divisor of the form 2^n + 1, at least for remainder if not quotient.  But on a binary computer, division by a number that isn't a power of 2 is fundamentally harder, that's why hardware divide / sqrt units are so much slower than HW multipliers, let alone shifters.

Comment: alright, thank you so much everyone for your feedback!